# Понять, что упаковано в object

Tags: c#, .net

Например, есть какой-то известный пользовательский тип(его либа есть в проекте), который приведен к типу object.

Можно ли без перебора типов понять, какой тип на самом деле находится в object и сделать приведение к настоящему типу?

Comment: если ты в compile-time Не знаешь тип в который надо разворачивать - то никак нельзя.

Comment: через `.GetType()` пробовали?

Comment: Не могу представить ситуацию, когда мне нужно приведение, к типу, который я не знаю и, соответственно не знаю, что с ним делать. Пожалуйста расскажите об исходной проблеме, откуда взялась такая задача.

Comment: @RuslanArtamonov, так можно только получить тип в качестве строки, привести объект к этому типу не получится

Comment: а зачем приведение? используй просто `dynamic` вроде этого `dynamic myObj = method.getSomeObject();`

Comment: @Grundy можно `Convert.ChangeType(o, o.GetType());` Но это не имеет смысла, ведь статически мы не знаем, что это за тип.

Comment: @RuslanArtamonov, при этому _ChangeType_ вернет тот же самый объект.

Comment: В общем понять, какой тип можно, и на самом деле объект уже приведен к этому типу, просто статически (в коде) мы об этом не знаем.

Comment: @FoggyFinder, просто интересно.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Если просто интересно, тогда NameSpace System.Reflection :).

Comment: @iluxa1810 вы можете привести к настоящему типу. проблема только в том, что результат приведения вам захочется положить в переменную. а тип переменной нужно указать при написании кода. А т.к. вы совсем не знаете, что за значение лежит в object - то тип у переменной вам придется задать как object.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Мне непонятна суть вопроса в плане его практической ценности.